# Segmentation fault en codigo de rot13 (C)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char rot13(char palabra[]) { //char *palabra
    int y = (short) strlen(palabra);
    char abc[27]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < y ; ++i) {
        if(palabra[i]<'m' && palabra[i]>='a'){
            for (int j = 0; j <26 ; ++j) {
                if (palabra[i]==abc[j]){
                    palabra[i]=abc[j+13];
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return palabra;
}

int main() {
    rot13("aaa");
    return 0;
}
```

Hola, estoy haciendo un codigo en c que hace encriptación ROT13, para eso mi idea es definir el abecedario, recorrerlo e intercambiar los caracteres que corresponden sumando 13... El codigo hasta ahora cubre solo el caso que suma 13 y me tira error "Segmentation fault" y además un warning que dice:

```
main.c:18:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return palabra;
```

Y que no entiendo cual es el problema, por si alguien me puede explicar como solucionar el problema y el warning, de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos problemas en tu código. Primero, que llamas a una función que devuelve algo char y tú lo estás llamando como si fuera void y...que si quieres que retorne una cadena de carácteres, no es del tipo char, sino char *, ya que lo que hace es crear una variable que almacene la cadena de caracteres pero, al retornar, devuelve el puntero hacia el primer caracter de la cadena.

Modifiqué tu código, espero esto te sirva:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rot13(char*,char*);

int main() {
    char prueba[50], enc[50];
    printf(" Ingrese una palabra: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",prueba);
    rot13(prueba,enc);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(enc);i++){
        printf("%c", enc[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void rot13(char *palabra, char *resultado) {
    char abc[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int larp=strlen(palabra);
    int i=0, j=0;
    for(i=0;i<larp;i++){
        for(j=0;j<26;j++){
            if(palabra[i]==abc[j]){
                resultado[i]=abc[j+13];
            }
        }
    }
    resultado[i]='\0';
}
```

Lo que hago es en efecto, declarar rot13 como void pero pasarle otro vector del mismo largo que el vector donde está la palabra, para guardar el texto encriptado.